# C# String ASCII representation

Tags: c#, regex, string, ascii

How can I insert ASCII special characters (e.g. with the ASCII value 0x01) into a string?

I ask because I am using the following:

```
str.Replace( "<TAG1>", Convert.ToChar(0x01).ToString() );
```

and I feel that there must be a better way than this. Any Ideas?

Update:

Also If I use this methodology, do I need to worry about unicode & ASCII clashing?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe you can use `\uXXXX` to insert specified codes into your string.

ETA: I just tested it and it works. :-)

```
using System;
class Uxxxx {
    public static void Main() {
        Console.WriteLine("\u20AC");
    }
}
```

Comment: Does the hex value after the '\u' represent an ASCII character?

Comment: It will, if the number is below 0x80.

Answer (score 1):

> Also If I use this methodology, do I need to worry about unicode & ASCII clashing?

Your first problem will be your tags clashing with ASCII. Once you get to TAG10, you will clash with 0x0A: line feed. If you ensure that you will never get more than nine tags, you should be safe. Unicode-encoding (or rather: UTF8) is identical to ASCII-encoding when the byte-values are between 0 and 127. They only differ when the top-bit is set.

Answer (score 1):

> and I feel that there must be a better
>   way than this. Any Ideas?

It looks as if you're trying to **manipulate a binary chunk using textual tools**. If you want to insert the byte `0x01`, for example, you're not manipulating text anymore, since you don't care what that byte *might* represent, and since it looks like you don't even care which encoding you'll be outputting.

A better way would be to treat the thing you're manipulating as a binary chunk of data, which would let you insert bits and bytes easily, without using brittle workarounds and worrying about side effects.

Comment: '\u0001' is a valid Unicode code point. Text/Binary is a matter of semantics.

Comment: @SebastianGodelet, not really. Unicode code points are mapped only to bytes by a Unicode translation format. For the example above, the Unicode code point u+0001 is represented by the byte 0x01 in *some* translation formats. So technically, when manipulating a binary chunk, you could figure out what combination of code point and translation format would map to the binary sequence you want to insert - if there is such a combination. Hardly semantics. :)

Comment: well but the OP is operating on a string already. SO he should hopefully not put binary data into a string to start with. And as the .NET string is using UTF-16, the \u0001 is a valid byte sequence describing the very same ASCII control character.

Comment: @SebastianGodelet, the OP is only *technically* operating on a string. What they're *really* trying to do is put binary data into a string, for example the value "0x01". For <TAG2>, the OP would put in 0x02, and so on. (On a side note, the fact that .NET uses UTF-16 *internally* isn't relevant here - the OP's example will do what you say because of how  `Convert.ToChar()` works, treating the argument as a Unicode code point number.)